# Webpack não usa o Babel para transpilar

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel

Sempre que executo o build do meu projeto, a saída é sempre o arquivo gerado pelo webpack, sem sinais que tenha passado pelo Babel.

As minhas configurações estão assim:

```
package.json
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:watch": "webpack -w --mode development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.28.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve('dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Na pasta src, tenho 3 arquivos: Product: Uma classe simples com 2 atributos; ProductController: Uma classe que importa Product e tem 2 métodos apenas (cria e lista os produtos com um console.log); e o app.js que tem um import do controller e instancia a classe e chama seu principal método.

O arquivo dist/main.js (o arquivo que está como output no arquivo de conf do webpack) sempre tem esse resultado:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./src/app.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./src/app.js":
/*!********************!*\
  !*** ./src/app.js ***!
  \********************/
/*! no exports provided */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony import */ var _controllers_ProductController__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./controllers/ProductController */ \"./src/controllers/ProductController.js\");\n\nvar controller = new _controllers_ProductController__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"ProductController\"]();\ncontroller.listProducts();\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/app.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/controllers/ProductController.js":
/*!**********************************************!*\
  !*** ./src/controllers/ProductController.js ***!
  \**********************************************/
/*! exports provided: ProductController */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"ProductController\", function() { return ProductController; });\n/* harmony import */ var _models_Product__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./../models/Product */ \"./src/models/Product.js\");\nfunction _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError(\"Cannot call a class as a function\"); } }\n\nfunction _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if (\"value\" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }\n\nfunction _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }\n\n\nvar ProductController =\n/*#__PURE__*/\nfunction () {\n  function ProductController() {\n    _classCallCheck(this, ProductController);\n  }\n\n  _createClass(ProductController, [{\n    key: \"addProduct\",\n    value: function addProduct() {\n      var products = [];\n      products.push(new _models_Product__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"Product\"]('Notebook', 900.0));\n      products.push(new _models_Product__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"Product\"]('Impressora', 900.0));\n      return products;\n    }\n  }, {\n    key: \"listProducts\",\n    value: function listProducts() {\n      this.addProduct().forEach(function (product) {\n        return console.log(product);\n      });\n    }\n  }]);\n\n  return ProductController;\n}();\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/controllers/ProductController.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/models/Product.js":
/*!*******************************!*\
  !*** ./src/models/Product.js ***!
  \*******************************/
/*! exports provided: Product */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"Product\", function() { return Product; });\nfunction _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError(\"Cannot call a class as a function\"); } }\n\nvar Product = function Product(name, price) {\n  _classCallCheck(this, Product);\n\n  this._name = name;\n  this._price = price;\n};\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/models/Product.js?");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

Acredito que se é pra ele passar pelo o Babel, a saída não seria essa. Alguém poderia dizer como posso configurar corretamente o projeto para que o Babel possa transpilar o js?